# How to scrape the whole information while using xpath selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, selector

I encountered a problem where I could not get all the information while using the XPath selector. The line is in developer mode. Is this

```
<address class="location-row-address" data-qa-target="provider-office-address">
230 W 13th St Ste 1b<!-- 
--> <!-- 
-->New York<!-- 
-->, <!--
-->NY<!-- 
--> <!-- 
-->10011<!--
--> 
</address>
```

The XPath selector that I use is

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/address/text()').get()
```

The result I am getting is

```
230 W 13th St Ste 1b
```

The result I am expecting is

```
230 W 13th St Ste 1b New York, NY 10011
```

I am using scrapy for scraping. Thank you. Your help is appreciated.

Edit:
The above problem I was facing was solved. I used the string() method and get() to get all the strings from the element node.

```
response.xpath('string(//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/address)').get()
```

Comment: You should be able to make this into a running example. You can remove most of the doc and the xpath selectors (maybe end up with <test><div>...your stuff... </div></test> and a selector to match). Then add code to read and display. That makes it easier to have tested solutions.

Comment: Okay, you are not going to make this easy. Try `.getall()` instead of `.get()`. You are selecting all of the text nodes but only getting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath expression returns all the text nodes which are children of the `address` element. There are several text nodes, with comment nodes separating them!

Back in Python land, you are calling the `get()` method on the result which returns you only the *first* node of the nodeset.

> .get() always returns a single result; if there are several matches,
> content of a first match is returned; if there are no matches, None is
> returned. .getall() returns a list with all results.
> https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

If you called the `getall()` method you would retrieve a list of strings, and you could concatenate them to produce the text you want. But a simpler method is to use the XPath function `string` to get the "string value" of the `address` element. In the XPath 1.0 spec it defines the string value of an element node this way:

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the
> string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in
> document order.
> https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes

Applying this function to the `address` element will return you a single string value, which you can then access using the `get()` method in Scrapy:

```py
response.xpath(
   'string(//*[@id="summary-section"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/address)'
).get()
```